# Can I use Schwartz's Lemma to prove that $f(0)=0$ and $\operatorname{Re}f(z)\rightarrow 0$ implies $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> **Problem.** Suppose that $f(x)$ is an entire function satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $\operatorname{Re}f(z)\rightarrow 0$ as $|z|\rightarrow \infty$.  Show that $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

The $f(0)=0$ thing makes me think I should use this theorem.

> **Schwartz's Lemma.** When $f$ is analytic in the open disc $\Delta(0,1)$, $f(0)=0$, and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for every $z\in \Delta$, then $|f'(0)|\leq 1$ and $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ for every $z\in \Delta$. Furthermore, equality is only possible if $f(z)=cz$ for $|c|=1$.

But I just can't see where to apply it.  Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: If you can show $\Re\, f(z)$ is bounded, you can apply Liouville's theorem to conclude that $f$ is constant. The fact that $f(0)=0$ implies $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: @Clayton But Liouville's theorem says that a bounded entire function is constant, right?  What if $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ is unbounded, so $|z|^2=(\operatorname{Re}(z))^2+(\operatorname{Im}(z))^2$ is unbounded?

Comment: Apply Liouville's theorem to $\exp(f)$.

Comment: Samuel, since the image of a nonconstant holomorphic function has a dense image in the plane, if $\Re\,f(z)$ is bounded, $f(z)$ would be constant. This is a corollary to Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @Clayton Hahahaha - actually, the *next* problem is exactly that.  "If $f(z)$ is a nonconstant, entire function then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$."

Comment: @SamuelHandwich: Well, what can I say? It's an effective corollary! Hint: use contradiction!

Comment: @Samuel, Please post an answer once you have it. Otherwise, this question will continue to look unanswered!

Comment: @julien: if the image is dense, then $\Re\,f(z)$ can't be bounded.

Comment: @Clayton Sure. Now I see you commented some time before posting your answer. So you gave two proofs that an analytic function with bounded real part is constant. In the answer: by Liouville directly. In the comment: by the apparently stronger (yet equivalent to Liouville) fact that a nonconstant entire function has dense range. I got confused because I read the answer before the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can show $\Re\,f(z)$ is bounded by using the fact that $f$ is entire and $\Re\,f(z)\to0$ as $|z|\to\infty$. Then we can say that $\left|\Re\,f(z)\right|<M$ for some $M\in\Bbb R$, and therefore $$g(z)=\frac{1}{2M-f(z)}$$is an entire, bounded (by $1/M$, for example) function, therefore $g(z)$ is constant by Liouville's theorem, hence $f(z)$ is constant. Since $f(0)=0$, $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Interesting way around $e^f$, +1. It would be slightly easier to read if you had $|\mbox{Re} f|\leq M$ and $g=1/(2M-f)$. And then it would be even easier if you said that $g$ is bounded by $1/M$. But I am only saying that because I did not see it right away...

Comment: @julien: I took your suggestions. I'm personally a fan of this technique :).

Comment: I had not seen it in a long time, and I did not think about it at all. I went to $e^f$ right away... So I really appreciate your answer.